# Eigen3 cannot find mkl.h on Linux

Tags: cmake, eigen3, intel-mkl

I am trying to compile a program with MKL support in Eigen3. However, I keep running into

```
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/MKL_support.h:58:13: fatal error: 'mkl.h' file not found
```

I have MKL installed via oneapi and MKL_ROOT is properly defined as an environment variable. mkl.h is on the system in /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/latest/include

The CMakeLists.txt file has the following info:

```
find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED)
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
find_package(MKL REQUIRED)
set(BLA_VENDOR Intel10_64lp)

add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} ${INCLUDE_FILES})

target_sources(${TARGET_NAME}
    PRIVATE main.cpp
            test_mkl.cpp
)

add_definitions(-DEIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL)

target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME}
    PRIVATE Eigen3::Eigen ${BLAS_LIBRARIES}
    ${MKL_LIBRARIES})

message("BLAS:")
message("${BLAS_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
if (MKL_FOUND)
    message("MKL")
    message("${MKL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
endif()

target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME}
    PRIVATE ../../include
    PRIVATE ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    PRIVATE ${MKL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    PRIVATE ${BLAS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

MKL is found, however MKL_INCLUDE_DIRS is empty. how do I get this to correctly pick up the MKL include directories.

Comment: Which script `FindMKL.cmake` do you use? CMake itself doesn't provide such script, so it should be shipped with your project. Exactly that script determines which variables are created by `find_package(MKL)` for reflect MKL properties.

Comment: BTW, REQUIRED keyword in the call to `find_package(MKL REQUIRED)` means, that in case of the package not found, CMake won't proceed further. So the check `if (MKL_FOUND)` is unnecessary and can be omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the tip of https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev I figured this out.

MKLConfig.cmake from oneapi does not create MKL_INCLUDE_DIRS, but MKL_INCLUDE.

Also MKL::MKL instead of MKL_LIBRARIES

Comment: If you link to `MKL::MKL`, then you do not need to do anything else regarding include directories for MKL.